# Plot different set of Y for a single set of X

Tags: gnuplot

I have a single set of value for X. Otherwise I have three set of Y values let it be y1,y3,y4.
Now, I am unable to plot X versus y1,y3,y4 in the same plot in GNUPLOT.
Can anyone help me out to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your data in a file, assuming `data.dat`

```
X1   Y1    Y2    Y3
1    0.1   0.2   0.3
...  ...   ...   ...
```

you can plot Y1, Y2 and Y3 versus X with

```
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2, '' u 1:3, '' u 1:4
```

`u` being the shortcut for `using`.

Comment: @Pascail..Thanks...it is working. But in the figure, on the top, 'data.dat' using 1:2 is appearing. How can I remove this?

Comment: With the `title` option, `plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 title "I'm a great plot"`.

Comment: You can find a lot of helpfull examples online (http://www.gnuplotting.org/ is a great ressource, and the user manual comes with great plots)

Answer (score 1):

If all y values are of the same units, then one y axis would suffice. If not, you can plot x against up to 2 y-axes ([here's how](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/multiaxis.html)).

Answer (score 1):

You use the 'axes' option to plot. Here is an example drawing 2 plots using the same X values:

```
set xrange [-4:4]
plot cos(x) axes x1y1 title "cos" with linespoints lt 1 pt 7 ps 0.0,\
     sin(x) axes x1y2 title "sin" with linespoints lt 2 pt 8 ps 0.0
pause mouse any "Click the mouse or hit any key to terminate"
```

If you run that with gnuplot it should look like the following image [image: example double plot]